# Custom names for predicted variable in spss

Tags: variables, regression, spss

The   /SAVE PRED. command creates a variable named "PRE_1"

Is there a way I can write a command that I want the saved variable to be named as "Italy_Model1_B_Predicted_Value"

Thanks

Comment: assuming you're using syntax - why not just put in a rename command after the analysis?    
`rename variables PRE_1=Italy_Model1_B_Predicted_Value.`

Comment: So what I am doing is running three regressions and then a Means, so I'd like to rename them in the syntax write after the regression so I can run my Means code which is : `MEANS TABLES=D IT_Swine_D_Model_1_Predicted_Value IT_Swine_D_Model_2_Predicted_Value
    IT_Swine_D_Model_3_Predicted_Value BY Year
  /CELLS=MEAN.`

Comment: Ok I just tried it and got what you said!! Woohooo. Thank you so much! PS. I'm not able to click /find the tick button to notify that it has been answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the linear regression procedure you can specify what you want to name the variable in parenthesis after the PRED keyword, e.g. `/SAVE PRED (Italy_Model1_B_Predicted_Value)`. It works the same way for many of the different regression procedures.

You can of course just use `RENAME VARIABLES` as eli-k stated in comments, but note if `PRE_1` already exists in the dataset, then SPSS will write the new predicted value as `PRE_2`.